# How view all css rules for class?

Tags: css, class, google-chrome, firefox, opera

Suppose I have several css files:

```
//first.css
my-style {
    color: blue;
}

//second.css
my-style {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Is there a way to enter class name "my-style" and see all rule in all css file for it in whole html page? (Interested in Firefox, Chrome and Opera).

Comment: Can Firebug in Firefox / Developer Console in modern Firefox & Chrome help? (Also, Fiddler or F12 Developer Tools in IE)

Comment: No and that would not make sense either (think about Why?). You can see the computed style rules for each element in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

No, I'm not aware of any such feature in any of the browsers. And I don't think that it would make sense either. For example, say you have following two style rules:

```
#someId .someClass{
  //rule set 1
}

.someClass {
  //rule set 2
}
```

So, what does it mean to have all rules for .someClass now? As you can see pretty clearly, some rules will apply to some elements while other rules will apply to other elements. With all the specificity and overriding rules that CSS has, two elements with the same class can have very different styles.

What indeed does make sense and is supported by Chrome is to see the computed style rules for an element. If you are debugging an issue, you can find out which rule is messing up your design and you can then look up the specificity chain to figure out the problematic rule.

Comment: read question attentively, first fules are in different css files. Second there several classes for *one* class, not several overridden class or/and rules.

Comment: Read your comment carefully - "there several classes for one class". What does it even mean?

Comment: Sorry. I have meant several rules for one class.